# Threads methods

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently I've had a java interview.  one of the questions was
Suppose there are two threads  and one thread is executing forever, How could we execute the other thread in this situation?   by calling **join()** or  **yield()** method?

Comment: You should ask a single question in one stackoverflow question.

Comment: okkie i 'll ask it in another  question

Comment: The answer would be pretty clear if you would dare to look into the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`join()` will wait for given thread to stop executing, so you will wait forever for the first thread.
`yield()`:

> A hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield its current use of a processor.

So you could use yield() in the first thread, but it is not necessary, threads are executed concurrently either way.

Comment: Okk What will happen if i am using synchronisation? it will still allow the thread to execute??

Comment: synchronized block is used to block access to given resource/object to a single thread

Comment: You should not think of `Thread.yield()` as "pausing" the calling thread.  The latest javadoc for `Thread.yield()` says that it is, "A _hint_ to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield its current use of a processor. _The scheduler is free to ignore this hint._"  (Emphasis mine.)  `Thread.yield()` really is an anachronism---intended for use in a JVM that runs on a single-CPU under a _cooperative multitasking_ operating system.

Comment: @jameslarge Yeah, I copied javadoc from java 7 previously, updated it to java 8 one.

Answer (score 0):

> How could we execute the other thread in this situation?

The question is very poorly stated.  *We* do not execute threads:  *Threads* execute our *code*.

If these two threads have both been `start()`ed on my laptop, and thread A is executing forever, and I want thread B to run also, then I don't have to do anything at all.  The operating system will insure that both threads get to run.  And, if there aren't any other programs trying to do work at the same time, then each thread will get approximately 100% of one of my laptop's eight CPUs.